# how to compute the global variance (square standard deviation) in a parallel application?

Tags: math, variance, standard-deviation

I have a parallel application in which I am computing in each node the variance of each partition of datapoint based on the calculated mean, but how can I compute the global variance (sum of all the variances)?

I thought that it would be a simple sum of the variances and divided by the number of nodes, but it is not giving me a close result...

Comment: Are you using the global mean to compute the variance of a subset, or some function that computes variance using the mean of just its input subset?

Comment: Hello aschepler!

I do not know if it is the correct way to compute the variance, what I do, I compute the mean in each node and based on that mean I compute the variance. 

If I sum all the means and divided by the number of nodes, I get nearly the global mean (maybe because some error propagation in the decimals), but for the variance (sigma square), if I try to do the same approach of computing the global mean, I get very different results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global variation is a *sum*.

You can compute parts of the sum in parallel trivially, and then add them together.

```
sum(x1...x100) = sum(x1...x50) + sum(x51...x100)
```

The same way, you can compute the global averages - compute the global sum, compute the sum of the object counts, divide (don't divide by the number of nodes; but by the total number of objects).

```
mean = sum/count
```

Once you have the mean, you can compute the sum of squared deviations using the distributed sum formula above (applied to (xi-mean)^2), then divide by count-1 to get the variance.

### Do not use E[X^2] - (E[X])^2

While this formula "mean of square minus square of mean" is highly popular, it is numerically unstable when you are using floating point math. It's known as [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation).
Because the two values can be very close, you lose a lot of digits in precision when computing the difference. I've seen people get a negative variance this way...

With "big data", numerical problems gets worse...

Two ways to avoid these problems:

- Use two passes. Computing the mean is stable, and gets you rid of the subtraction of the squares.
- Use an online algorithm such as the one by Knuth and Welford, then use weighted sums to combine the per-partition means and variances. [Details on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Parallel_algorithm) In my experience, this often is slower; but it may be beneficial on Hadoop due to startup and IO costs.

Comment: Hello Anony-Mousse, I mean the global variance (sigma squared), assuming I am computing a variance in each node.

Comment: Yes. Look at the formula. It is a sum, too. **Any sum** can be computed naive parallel. Although with variance, your numerical precision may suffer (but as the global variance is pretty much meaningless, who cares about precision).

Comment: For improved numerical precision, compute the mean in a first pass, then the squared deviations from the mean in a second pass. **Don't use E[X^2]-E[X]^2.**

Comment: so I compute the global mean first and in the second iteration I compute the squared deviations?

Comment: That is the easiest numerically stable version. There are online algorithms that provide reasonable performance (see Knuth, the art of computer programming); but they require more computations. In many cases, two passes is the fastest way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the sums and sums of squares of each partition to get the global sum and sum of squares and then use them to calculate the global mean and variance.

**UPDATE**: E[X<sup>2</sup>] - E[X]<sup>2</sup> and cancellation...

To figure out how important cancellation error is when calculating the standard deviation with

σ = √(E[X<sup>2</sup>] - E[X]<sup>2</sup>)

let us assume that we have both E[X<sup>2</sup>] and E[X]<sup>2</sup> accurate to 12 significant decimal figures. This implies that σ<sup>2</sup> has an error of order 10<sup>-12</sup> × E[X<sup>2</sup>] or, if there has been significant cancellation, equivalently 10<sup>-12</sup> × E[X]<sup>2</sup> when σ will have an error of approximate order 10<sup>-6</sup> × E[X]; one *millionth* the mean.
For many, if not most, statistical analyses this is *negligable*, in the sense that it falls within other sources of error (like measurement error), and so you can in good consciense simply set negative variances to zero before you take the square root.

If you really do care about deviations of this magnitude (and can show that it's a feature of the thing you are measuring and not, for example, an artifact of the method of measurement) then you can start worrying about cancellation. That said, the most likely explanation is that you have used an inappropriate scale for your data, such as measuring daily temperatures in Kelvin rather than Celcius!

Comment: Hello thus, after I get the global sum and global sum of squares, do I have to divide them for the number of partitions?

Comment: **Don't use E[X^2]-E[X]^2.** This is numerically unstable, *in particular for big data*.